# Magento 2 - Custom Widget Wysiwyg Editor allow html tags

Tags: magento2, html, widget, wysiwyg

I try to add a wysiwyg editor to my custom widget.

I added the field to my widget.xml

```
            <parameter name="content" xsi:type="block" required="false" visible="true" sort_order="60">
                <label>Content</label>
                <block class="Test\Custom\Block\Widget\Editor" />
            </parameter>
```

and this is my Editor.php :

```
<?php

namespace Test\Custom\Block\Widget;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

class Editor extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config
     */
    protected $_wysiwygConfig;

    /**
     * @var Factory
     */
    protected $_factoryElement;

    /**
     * @param Factory $factoryElement
     * @param CollectionFactory $factoryCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $factoryElement,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_factoryElement = $factoryElement;
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare chooser element HTML
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element Form Element
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
     */
    public function prepareElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $editor = $this->_factoryElement->create('editor', ['data' => $element->getData()])
            ->setLabel('')
            ->setForm($element->getForm())
            ->setWysiwyg(true)
            ->setConfig($this->_wysiwygConfig->getConfig(['add_variables' => false, 'add_widgets' => false]));

        if ($element->getRequired()) {
            $editor->addClass('required-entry');
        }

        $element->setData(
            'after_element_html', $this->_getAfterElementHtml() . $editor->getElementHtml()
        );

        return $element;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getAfterElementHtml()
    {
        $html = <<<HTML
            <style>
                .admin__field-control.control .control-value {
                    display: none !important;
                }
            </style>
        HTML;

        return $html;
    }

}
```

If i try to get the Editor value to my frontend like this :

```
<?= $block->getData('content');?>
```

or like this :

```
 <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getData('content')) ?>
```

[image]

it shows the HTML Tags in Frontend.
How can i "allow" html tags for my wysiwyg editor?